# PHP into HTML code

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone check why this code not run ?
Sorry for my bad english

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>LetteLariaMente</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="drop-menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Chi_siamo.html">Chi siamo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Le nostre attività</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Concorsi.html">Concorsi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Eventi.html">Eventi</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Partner.html">I nostri partner</a></li>
                <li><a href="Iscriviti.html">Iscriviti</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Amministrazione.html">Amministrazione</a></li>
                            <li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="logomenu.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<table border="5" align="right" width="70%" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<th rowspan="2" style="width:70%; height=20">
<marquee onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);" scrollamount=3 scrolldelay=1 direction=right width="100%" height="100%">
<img src="DONNEDONNE.jpg">
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<img src="man_piccoli_editori.jpg">
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<img src="sottocipressi.jpg">
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<img src="manifesto_libr__da_bere.jpg">
</marquee>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$name = "";
$tabella = "";
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db("$name");
$query="SELECT * FROM $tabella";
$ris=mysql_query($query);
$n=mysql_numrows($ris);
echo "<table><tr><td bgcolor="#000000"><img src="prossimi_app.png"></td></tr>";
if($n < 1)
{
echo "<tr><td>Nessun appuntamento</td></tr>";
}
if($n < 4 && $n > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($ris))
{
   echo "<tr style="border:1px solid green">";
   $i=0;    
   while($i<4)
   {
   echo "<td style="border:1px solid green; background:cyan">" . $row["$i"] . "</td>";
   $i++;    
   }
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The php code is not working as it should. It writes the code directly in the page without using it as php code.
It seems that from a point on will not read more PHP and I do not understand why. I think it's the inclusion of php code in html page to create problems.

Comment: You probably have mistakes in your webserver configuration.. are you using Apache?  Which OS?  what is the file called?

Comment: Your PHP and html syntax are both horrible. You've got mis-terminated strings, bad character entities... e.g. the script is nothing but a mass of syntax errors.

Comment: I can't even follow your code. Indentations should be properly used & you should look into a templating engine to separate HTML/PHP

Comment: Have you installed PHP? Is the file extension `.php`? Have you attempted to run a simple "Hello, world!" script?

Comment: SYNTAX ERRORS! syntax errors everywhere

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 1):

Is the php code included in a .html file?

Sometimes I forget to switch the file ending to .php when I add php to an old html file.

Comment: Thanks so much, the problem is the ending of file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver is configured incorrectly. Make sure PHP is actually running through the file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

> "

with

> '

inside echo statements.

```
<td bgcolor="#000000">
```

causes problem

EDIT: like below example

```
echo "<table><tr><td bgcolor='#000000'><img src='prossimi_app.png'></td></tr>";
```

EDIT2: this only solves your syntax problems. Your php configurations are also incorrect. Check php documents